# Android Google Maps Maritime charts layers

Tags: android, maps, layer

I'm looking at displaying a map within my Android app that presents maritime charts, and also needs to work offline as there will be no network connectivity of any type available. I suspect that I will get my maritime charts supplied as a series of bitmap files with LAT/LON references of the area clipped.

My question is this - how do I go about implementing this ? I guess I have to add them as a layer somehow, can someone show me how to do this ?

Also, as the device will be offline, will there be a problem trying to use Google maps even if all the content is held locally, will the API just "not work" until it has connectivity ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this just earned Tumbleweed, I thought I should update it.
I tried really hard to use the Maps API offline, with my bitmap as a layer - it didn't work out. The API is too reliant on the interweb and just seems to timeout when trying just about anything.

Simple solution, I have just extended the ImageView class to display my bitmap chart & overlays.